# go to action gets 404 on admin

Tags: admin, module, backend, forms, login

I'm trying to add a form to the admin login.  I just get a 404 currently but this is where I'm sending the user:

http://local.mage.dev/index.php/wsu_adminldap/index/requestaccess/

I have the controller app\code\local\Wsu\Adminldap\controllers\IndexController.php

```
<?
class Wsu_Adminldap_IndexController extends Mage_Adminhtml_IndexController {

        public function indexAction(){
            $this->loadLayout();
            $this->renderLayout();      
        }

    /**
     * Forgot administrator password action
     * Request Access 
     */
    public function requestaccessAction() {
        $email    = (string) $this->getRequest()->getParam('email');
        $store_id = (string) $this->getRequest()->getParam('store');
        $params   = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
        if (!empty($email) && !empty($params)) {
            $this->_getSession()->addError($this->__('This account already exists.'));  

        } elseif (!empty($params)) {
            $this->_getSession()->addError(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('The email address is empty.'));
        }
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

and the config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Wsu_Adminldap>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Wsu_Adminldap>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <helpers>
      <wsu_adminldap>
        <class>Wsu_Adminldap_Helper</class>
      </wsu_adminldap>
    </helpers>
    <blocks>
      <wsu_adminldap>
        <class>Wsu_Adminldap_Block</class>
      </wsu_adminldap>
    </blocks>
    <models>
      <wsu_adminldap>
        <class>Wsu_Adminldap_Model</class>
      </wsu_adminldap>
      <admin>
        <rewrite>
          <session>Wsu_Adminldap_Model_Session</session>
          <Observer>Wsu_Adminldap_Model_Observer</Observer>
        </rewrite>
      </admin>
    </models>
  </global>
  <admin>
    <routers>
      <adminhtml>
        <args>
          <modules>
            <wsu_adminldap before="Mage_Adminhtml">Wsu_Adminldap_Adminhtml</wsu_adminldap>
          </modules>
        </args>
      </adminhtml>
    </routers>
  </admin>
</config>
```

and the view app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\wsu\adminldap\requestaccess.phtml

```
<?php
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title><?php echo Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Log into Magento Admin Page'); ?></title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('reset.css'); ?>" media="all" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('boxes.css'); ?>" media="all" />
    <link rel="icon" href="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('favicon.ico'); ?>" type="image/x-icon" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('favicon.ico'); ?>" type="image/x-icon" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->getJsUrl(); ?>index.php/x.js?f=prototype/prototype.js,prototype/validation.js,mage/adminhtml/events.js,mage/adminhtml/form.js,scriptaculous/effects.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->getJsUrl('mage/captcha.js') ?>"></script>

    <!--[if IE]> <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('iestyles.css'); ?>" type="text/css" media="all" /> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if lt IE 7]> <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('below_ie7.css'); ?>" type="text/css" media="all" /> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 7]> <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('ie7.css'); ?>" type="text/css" media="all" /> <![endif]-->
</head>
<body id="page-login">
    <div class="login-container">
        <div class="login-box">
            <form method="post" action="" id="loginForm">
                <fieldset class="login-form">
                    <input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $this->getFormKey(); ?>" />
                    <h2><?php echo Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Forgot your user name or password?'); ?></h2>
                    <div id="messages">
                        <?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml(); ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-box forgot-password"><label for="email"><?php echo Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Email Address:'); ?></label><br />
                        <input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="" class="required-entry input-text forgot-password validate-email" style="width:461px;" />
                    </div>
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('form.additional.info'); ?>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    <div class="form-buttons">
                        <a class="left" href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('adminhtml', array('_nosecret' => true)); ?>">&laquo; <?php echo Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Back to Login'); ?></a>
                        <button class="forgot-password" onclick="loginForm.submit()" type="button"><span><?php echo Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Retrieve Password'); ?></span></button>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
                <p class="login-support"><!-- --></p>
                <p class="legal"><?php echo Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Magento is a trademark of Magento Inc. Copyright &copy; %s Magento Inc.', date('Y')); ?></p>
            </form>
            <div class="bottom"></div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                 var loginForm = new varienForm('loginForm');
            </script>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Am I missing or overlooking something to bring up the form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put your controller in:
app\code\local\Wsu\Adminldap\controllers\Adminhtml\WsuController.php

and then use the route:

http://local.mage.dev/index.php/admin/wsu/requestaccess/

This is because you define in your config.xml that your controller extends the adminhtml controller and runs before it using the path

```
<wsu_adminldap before="Mage_Adminhtml">Wsu_Adminldap_Adminhtml</wsu_adminldap>
```

So Magento looks in the folder `app\code\local\Wsu\Adminldap\controllers\Adminhtml` for anything served at http://local.mage.dev/index.php/admin/* where * is the name of the controller (above I said wsu, so you need a WsuController.php in that folder).

Make sure to rename the controller also in your php file from IndexController to WsuController!